# string to json converter laravel return data json_encode

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
"[{"question":false,"choices":["Database","Email","Command line"],"correctAnswer":1},{"question":false,"choices":["Horizon","Sunset","Nightfall"],"correctAnswer":1}]"
```

convert to this

```
[{"question":false,"choices":["Database","Email","Command line"],"correctAnswer":1},{"question":false,"choices":["Horizon","Sunset","Nightfall"],"correctAnswer":1}]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: I am try this code but not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of (Invalid string)

```
"[{"question":false,"choices":["Database","Email","Command line"],"correctAnswer":1},{"question":false,"choices":["Horizon","Sunset","Nightfall"],"correctAnswer":1}]"
```

Use this

```
'[{"question":false,"choices":["Database","Email","Command line"],"correctAnswer":1},{"question":false,"choices":["Horizon","Sunset","Nightfall"],"correctAnswer":1}]'
```

For example :

```
var str = '[{"question":false,"choices":["Database","Email","Command line"],"correctAnswer":1},{"question":false,"choices":["Horizon","Sunset","Nightfall"],"correctAnswer":1}]'
console.log(JSON.parse(str))
```

**Reason:
If there is double quote inside a string then you can not use a double quote to enclose that string. As there is always a double quote inside a JSON string, you can use a single quote('') or a template string (``) to enclose it.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` because It's already stringified.